# What actions reward experience?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

Some basic actions like kills, assists, healing, damaging buildings and capturing resource points reward XP, but are there other more obscure actions you can do to increase your XP gain and are there any bonus XP rewarded at end of round for winning or doing specific tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XP is awarded for:

- Killing Opponents (+10)
- Headshotting Opponents (+5)
- Assisting Kills (+5, more if critical assist)
- Neutralizing Resource Point (depends on type, +5/+10/+15 IIRC)
- Capturing Resource Point (depends on type, +10/+15/+20 IIRC)
- Healing (+10 every x amount of health, +15 for healing multiple players)
- Hypospraying (+5)
- Damaging buildings (+10 every x amount of damage)
- Repairing buildings (+10 every x amount of repair)

Bonus on XP:

- Being in a squad
- Following commander orders

XP loss:

- Suiciding (-10)

I don't recall any other action giving XP.

Source: Me

Comment: Headshot: +5
Critical Assist: +5
Squad Assist: +4

Comment: Thanks, forgot about those. IIRC squad assist is just a bonus on assist if you are in a squad, i.e. you just get more XP for the same thing.

Comment: Healing multiple people at the same time gives 15 points each tick instead of 10